# How to generate a table to show the separated outputs in R

Tags: r

I have several separated values. Mean, SD, Skewness, and slope are numbers (num).

```
df1 for mean
23
df2 for SD
2.1
df3  for Skeweness
0.56
df4  for Slope
3.1
```

I would like to get the following named data frame:

```
Mean    SD  SKewness    Slope
23     2.1    0.56          3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you could do this:

Your initial data:

```
df1 <- 23
df2 <- 2.1
df3 <- 0.56
df4 <- 3.1
```

Create a data frame, then name its values:

```
df <- data.frame(df1, df2, df3, df4)

names(df) <- c("mean", "SD", "Skeweness", "Slope")
```

Or, if you prefer to use `setNames()`, as a one liner:

```
setNames(data.frame(df1, df2, df3, df4),
         c("mean", "SD", "Skeweness", "Slope"))
```

Output:

```
  mean  SD   Skeweness  Slope
  23    2.1  0.56       3.1
```